# Reliably using analogRead as a compact digitalRead

Tags: analogread, performance, capacitors, algorithm

My goal is to reduce pins being used for micro-controllers with limited pins, or projects requiring a few different digital input values.

How I intend to do so is by using ADC pins to gather four specific different values through resistors with analogRead, which would otherwise need 2 pins (!A+!B, !A+B, A+!B, and A+B).

```
value = analogRead(adcPin1) >> 8;
```

This would give, if properly wired, 4 possible results like some sort of "Quartary bit", as analogRead yields a 10-bit response.

So my questions are the following:

- Can analogRead be sufficiently reliable to tell the difference between four possible values?
- What would the wiring/casing/etc. need to look like to prevent any errors?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how reliable it is, but it seems to be a [quite](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Multiple-Buttons-on-1-Analog-Pin-Arduino-Tu/) [commonly](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=8558.0) [used](https://rayshobby.net/wordpress/multiple-button-inputs-using-arduino-analog-pin/) [technique](https://tronixstuff.com/2011/01/11/tutorial-using-analog-input-for-multiple-buttons/).

Comment: Thank you Edgar that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you I don't know why I missed on the research :/

Comment: There are 5-button-pads (https://www.sainsmart.com/products/lcd-keypad-shield-for-arduino-duemilanove-uno-mega2560-mega1280) available using this technique. It assumes you press only one of the buttons at a time. Just an info, no advertising, no recommendation :)